# Create custom Tokens after successful payment

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I would like to create a Website where people can buy Giftcards with money values.
I cant explain the project in detail, but my idea is that a user can select a value for example 25$ | 50$ | 100$
and type their email and when they go to the payment gateway, they select their payment option and proceed the payment.
if the payment was successful, they get redirected to a screen where they see a recipe of the payment and a new generated unique token that they can use to reedem on the page.
im not sure what im looking for or how its called.
Do i need to generate tokens and after payment my script hands one token out or is it possible to generate a token after an successful payment?